# how to make a managed custom object in customer's org api only?

Tags: apex, api, managed-package, custom-object, security

MetricsDataFile Object from SF is API only (query and delete access). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/usage_metrics_metricsdatafile_object.htm

We have our own custom object in our managed package and imilar to MetricsDataFile, we don't want the end user to be able to see/edit any fields on the Salesforce UI. How can this be done?

Comment: What kind of data are you looking to store? how many records? how many fields?

Comment: take insurance coverage as an example: fields could be a variety (including lookups (agent = lookup to contacts), text, formulas etc...), roughly 30-50 fields, record numbers would be in the thousands per org.

Answer (score 0):

Once installed in an org, the subscriber has the ability to change any of the unprotected attributes of the object, including visibility to users, adding a custom tab (if one is not yet defined), managing list views, and so on. You can't prevent them from setting whatever security measures they choose.